# jQuery show hide div based on textbox value (cloned rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide DIVs using the textbox value.

```
$('input[name=SelName]').each(function() {
var ClassVal = $(this).val();

if(ClassVal == "Value01") { $('#image1').show(); }
else { $('#image1').hide(); }

if(ClassVal == "Value02") { $('#image2').show(); }
else { $('#image2').hide(); }

if(ClassVal == "Value03") { $('#image3').show(); }
else { $('#image3').hide(); }

});
```

First row: if SelName value is Value01 div "image1" shown, if SelName value is Value02 div "image2" shown...

But if the first row SelNmame has value Value01 and second cloned row SelName has value Value02, "image1" div remain hidden and only div "image02" shown. And this is a problem.

I want both divs "image1" and "image2" to be shown.

And if the first row SelNmame has value Value02 and the second line SelNmame has value Value02, show only div "image2".

Must I use the closest('tr') and find("[id^=' ']").val() instead ???

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3777/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3778/)

Just hide all divs first, and then show all you want after:

```
$('#image1').hide(); // add this
$('#image2').hide(); // add this
$('#image3').hide(); // add this

$('input[name=SelName]').each(function() {
    var ClassVal = $(this).val();

    if(ClassVal == "Value01") { $('#image1').show(); }
    // remove this: else { $('#image1').hide(); }

    if(ClassVal == "Value02") { $('#image2').show(); }
    // remove this: else { $('#image2').hide(); }

    if(ClassVal == "Value03") { $('#image3').show(); }
    // remove this: else { $('#image3').hide(); }
});
```